# Document.getElementByClassName not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Document.getElementByClassName, but it isn't working. I've included my code below. I'd appreciate any help.

HTML document:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Day Practice</title>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class=myclass> Some text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
var change = document.getElementByClassName("myclass");
change.innerHTML = "New text";
```

Comment: @SeanF Not required in HTML5

Answer (score 6):

It's `getElementsByClassName` Element**s**

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names 
>   - [Mozilla Developer Network / Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Loop through it or use `change[0].innerHTML`

### 1

```js
   var change = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
   change[0].innerHTML = "New text";
```

```html
 <h1 class="myclass"> Some text</h1>
```

### 2

```js
   var change = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");

   for (var i = 0; i < change.length; i++) {
     change[i].innerHTML = "New text";
   }
```

```html
 <h1 class="myclass"> Some text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right before the closing body tag (), you want to add a script tag to attach your JavaScript file into the HTML file, so that they're both linked.

This is how it should look:

```
<head>
 <meta charset=utf-8>
 <title>Day Practice</title>
 <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class=myclass> Some text</h1>
  <script src="javascriptfile.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also, it's "getElementsByClassName"; elements is plural